# vertical column in table Display query result horizontally in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql, pivot-table

i want to display vertical values of the field , horizontally in html table. 
my table structure is like

```
ID Category Value     (ID is Foriegn Key)
1     A      23
1     B      25
.
.
.
.
1   S      30
2   A      10
2   B      11
.
.
.
2   S      22
ID Area_A  Area_B Area_C  (ID is primary key)
```

i want to join these table   and want to display query result horizontally like

```
ID Area_A  Area_B  Area_C  A   B  ........ S
1  aa      bb      cc      23  25         30
```

can anyone help me?
 is this possible ?

```html
$sql = "select * from tbl1, tbl2 where tble1.ID = tble2._ID ";
  $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
  ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->ID"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Area_A"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Area_B"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Area_C; ?></td>
          
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value "; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo "$row->Value"; ?></td>
                                        </tr>
         <?php
```

but the problem is inserted data like this

[image]

this black ellipse should display horizontally and only once

Comment: Please see how to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), edit your question to be more specific and show your attempt to solve it.

Comment: How many rows of data will appear in your output HTML display? If your HTML table has more than one row of data, how do you tell from your data which MySQL row goes into which HTML table row? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Where/how did you get aa bb and cc? I dont see it in the sample data.

Comment: @O.Jones it is selected on the basis of id. one id has many categeories as i have edited

Comment: Follow this Site,Hopefully you'll solve your problem : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119144/select-from-vertical-table-and-display-on-horizontal-table

Comment: @MaijiedHasanShuvo thanks for the help. but i have one problem i have two table. primary and foriegn keys

Comment: kindly guide me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Smells like a dup.  Did you post this somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Your php code in your example creates a row in your HTML table for every row in your result set from MySQL. Change that code to create columns.  php is excellent for this sort of thing; it manipulates text and HTML tables are just text.

To do this you need to, actually, create two rows. One is the header row and the other the detail row.

Try something like this. Please notice that this code is not debugged.

```
$hdr = "";
$dat = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
   $hdr = $hdr + "<td>" + $row->Category + "</td>";
   $dat = $dat + "<td>" + $row->Value    + "</td>";
}
echo "<tr>" + $hdr + "</tr>";
echo "<tr>" + $dat + "</tr>";
```

Do you see how `$hdr = $hdr + table cell` accumulates a bunch of table cells for each data item, containing the `Category` values in your result set?  Likewise, `$dat = $dat + table cell` accumulates a bunch of table cells for each data item.

Sorry to say I don't understand `Area_A` and the other area items in your question, so I haven't tried to program those.